# entity framework 6.1 - assign a forigen key cause to an insertion of new record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I seen similar posts but didn't find an answer. I have WPF 4.5 application with EF 6.1.

Here is my part of my data model:

```
[Key]
[Required]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(32)]
public string FileDisplayName { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(32)]
public string FileName { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(8)]
public string FileExtention { get; set; }

[StringLength(1024)]
public string Description { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(1024)]
public string FilePath { get; set; }

[Required]
public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

[Required]
public virtual FilesTypeLookup FileType { get; set; }

[Required]
[DefaultValue(0)]
public double Amount { get; set; }

[Required]
public virtual Expenses ExpenseId { get; set; }

public virtual ExpensesCategories Category { get; set; }

public virtual ExpensesPayees Payee { get; set; }



public class ExpensesCategories
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `File` entity has `ExpensesCategory` navigation property.
The problem happens when I'm assigning new value for this property.
I'm using the next code to editing existing `File` record:

```
   var fileEntity = entityToEdit.Files.Single(p => p.Id == file.Id);
                                fileEntity.Amount = file.Amount;
                                fileEntity.Category = DB.ExpensesCategories.Single(p => p.Id == file.Category.Id);
//more work here
context.SaveChanges();
```

The `SaveChanges()` method is firing an exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Int32 SaveChanges()
UpdateException An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Int32 Update()
SqlException Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ExpensesCategories' with unique index 'IX_Name'. The duplicate key value is (חומרי יצירה).
The statement has been terminated. Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1[System.Action])
```

It seems that instead of create a relationship between existing `File` record to existing `ExpenseCategory`, EF is trying to create a new `ExpenseCategory` record and link it with my existing `File` record. The unique constraint does not allows it and fires the exception.

I don't want that EF will create new `ExpenseCategory` records, just want to set relationships with existing records (`ExpenseCategory` is look-up table). 
How can I do this?

Thanks
Ofir

Comment: how do you define the relationship between File and ExpenseCategory?  I think the problem is that you don't have that relationship well defined.

Comment: @JotaBe, This exactly like you see above: File entity have `public virtual ExpensesCategories Category { get; set; }` property and that it. EF code first is quite new for me, Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is one to one relationship between two objects
you should add the following properties to the ExpensesCategories

```
[Key, ForeignKey("File")]    
public int FileId {get;set;}

public virtual File File{ get; set;}
```

In my opinion the relation ship between ExpensesCatrgories and Files is one to many (one category has may files but each file belongs to a specific category). In this case please add

```
public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
```

to the ExpensesCategories

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, add this to the ExpensesCategories class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Files> Files { get; set; }
```

Not sure if that will fix it but it's something that's missing anyway.